# Upgrade to Mesa 10.5.9 from 10.1.3

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, mesa

I have some issues with my graphic card that I'm trying to solve. I have done some research and one solution could it be to use the latest mesa 10.5.9 but apparently I don't have it installed. How do I do this upgrade?

There is also this other problem: it seems that this line "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)" is making my CPU do all the work. Indeed the Xorg-process is usually 20% in "top" when I use xfce, and gnome-shell is 90%!

Is this problem related with this older version of Mesa?

```
    OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I shoud have mentioned it! I'm using xubuntu 15.10

Comment: Mesa in 15.10 is 11.0.2. So something is not true.

Comment: It is more likely that you are using 14.10.

Comment: oh boy, that is a mayor mistake :S. Sorry, I must have downloaded the wrong file, it is indeed the 14.04 lts of xubuntu. How do I upgrade? Can the upgrade be influenced by the fact that I installed the kernel 4.4?

Comment: Why do you want 10.5.9? You can install 11+

Comment: Of course, that would it be perfect. I didn't know the 11+ was the latest I thought the 10.5.9 was. Would the 11+ be automatically installed if I upgrade?

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-wily libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386
```

and it will install mesa 11.0.2.

Comment: perfect. Mayabe I should upgrade as well? I wanted to install the 15.10 but myabe it's not important since I have an updated kernel version, the 4.4 (I believe 15.10 comes with 4.2)

Comment: You will get exactly the same graphical stack including mesa as in 15.10.

Comment: I run the command but I got an error message and after reboot I got black screen. I reinstalled kubuntu 15.10 and add kernel 4.4 now I don't have problems like CPU usage but the screen gets all black very often making it impossible to work.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: I don't remember, it was something with dpkg having problem to overwrite in some folders

Comment: You should post the error, not just reboot. But after re-install it is not related.

Comment: Yes I know, sorry I didn't, I thought that it wasn't so severe to cause the black screen issue